# Как называется класс, у которого все поля (свойства) открытые

Tags: c#, .net, классы, терминология

Яркий пример - модели в том же EntityFramework на .NET.

Точно помню, что где-то видел "научное" название таких классов, но как именно...

Их задача, в большинстве случаев - служить как раз-таки своеобразной обёрткой над набором данных для их передачи в метод или куда-то ещё.

Не обёртка, не модель, не упаковка... на языке вертится.

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это DTO: Data Transfer Object.